# Passing a 2D array to a function / constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, arguments

### Can't convert float[3][3] to float **

I am writing a Program deal with Matrices as a practice for learning

But I am getting an error and am unable to assign `float matrix[3][3]` to `float**`
I know that a `2D array` is a Pointer of pointer, so a `float **`

My aim for this project is to write a Simple `Matrix` class to create matrices and do some basic matrix operations like addition and multiplication.

### I am getting the following error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
./matrix.h:12:5: note: candidate: Matrix::Matrix(int, int, float**)
     Matrix(int, int, float **elements);
     ^~~~~~
./matrix.h:12:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from 
‘float [3][3]’ to ‘float**’
```

I know that changing the argument type from `float[3][3]` will solve it. But the size of the Matrix is not fixed, that's why I was opting for `float**`

### This is the a part of my code:

> main.cpp

```
#include"Matrix.h"

int main()
{
    float Identity[3][3] = 
    {
        {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}    
    };
    
    Matrix identity = Matrix(3, 3, Identity);
}
```

> Matrix.h

```
class Matrix
{
private
    MatrixData _matrix = MatrixData();
    
    Matrix(int rows, int columns, float **elements)
    {
        _matrix.rows = rows;
        _matrix.columns = columns;
        
        _matrix.elements = new float[rows * columns];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                _matrix.elements[(i * columns) + j] = elements[i][j];

    }    
}
```

> MatrixData.h

```
struct MatrixData
{
    unsigned char rows;
    unsigned char columns;
    float *elements;
};
```

In the `MatrixData class`, elements are stored as a contiguous array.

To create a new Matrix a `2D array` has to be passed int he class `constructor`.

If the constructor arg type is `float *`
And I pass `Identity[0]` in the constructor, it works.

What I want is, to pass `Identity` and not something like `Identity[0]` or `&Identity[0][0]`.

Can Anyone tell me what could the solution.

Thank You.

Comment: 2D array is stored contiguously, why should it be convertible into `float**`? What does the second pointer stand for? Consider `float*` instead.

Comment: The elements in the `Matrix` class are stored in a contiguous array, but the elements are passed in as a `2D array` to make it readable. `_matrix.elements` is a `float*`

Comment: I tried passing `Identity[0]` to the constructor and changed the arg type to `float *`. It worked! Thanks Evg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2D arrays are stored contigously, so you should probably do something like this example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N1, size_t N2>
void output(const float (&elements)[N1][N2])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N1; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N2; j++)
            std::cout << elements[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
int main()
{

    float elements[3][3] = {
    {1,2,3},
    {1,2,3},
    {1,2,3}
    };
    output<3, 3>(elements);
}
```

**Note how I've used templates because the array size is static, which is another mistake you did**

Edit: I understand what you're trying to do, here's how:

Make the Matrix class a template class taking the template parameters rows and columns, and change the `elements` parameter into `float elements[rows][columns]`

```
template<size_t rows, size_t columns>
class Matrix
{
private:
    MatrixData _matrix = MatrixData();
public:
    Matrix(float elements[rows][columns])
    {
        _matrix.rows = rows;
        _matrix.columns = columns;

        _matrix.elements = new float[rows * columns];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                _matrix.elements[(i * columns) + j] = elements[i][j];

    }
};
```

Then you have to remove the rows and columns constructor parameters because you already have them as template parameters.

Now the object declaration should look like this:

```
int main()
{
    float Identity[3][3] =
    {
        {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
    };

    Matrix<3, 3> identity(Identity);
}
```

Comment: `elements` needs to be a reference. Are you sure this compiles?

Comment: @cigien Yes it compiles perfectly fine on GDB and Visual C++

Comment: Aah, I see, you're calling it with `output<3,3>(elements);`. But this makes the parameter of `output` be a dynamic array, not a reference to a static array. Which is fine, I suppose.

Comment: Hey Bily, I want to pass this `2D array` in  a constructor. I tried to put a template on the class constructor but on compilation I am getting an error saying `Matrix` is not a template. If its possible can you show me how?

Comment: @DhruvVanjari, add details into your question. Without seeing the code, its hard to understand what you want and what the problem is.

Comment: @DhruvVanjari can you show the code of the MatrixData class? It'd be better so that I can understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @BilyDev I have edited my post, what I want is to make my code more readable. Thats why I was wondering if I could directly pass `Identity` in the constructor. I have Also given a solution in which `Identity[0]` has to be passed

Comment: @BilyDev Thanks a lot for your help, I am accepting your answer.

Comment: You are making a copy of the array in the output function. It could have been `output(const float (&elements)[N1][N2])`